# Detect a Rigidbody position (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning to program in C#, specially with Unity and I have a problem:
I'm trying to move the camera if a sphere (with a Rigidbody) pass certain point, for example, if the sphere's *x* position is greater than 5 then move the camera.

The movement of the camera it's done (with an animation) but the detection of the position isn't working. I'm doing this:

```
if (PlayerController.playerPos.position.x > 5.5f) {
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger ("NextCamera01");
}
```

**PlayerController.playerPos** is the transform component of the sphere
(I've alse tried to do it with the rigidbody component and it isn't working neither.)

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working". Is the transform null?

Comment: Doesn't look like you are getting anything with your GetComponent. Should that instead be, `GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("NextCamera01");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code mentioned above, i don't see any issue in condition. that's perfect.
Just make sure that the transform is assigned to your playerPos variable and try Debug.Log with that code like..

```
    if (PlayerController.playerPos.position.x > 5.5f)
        Debug.Log ("Trigger action at player pos " + PlayerController.playerPos.position.x);
    else
        Debug.Log ("Wait for player pos " + PlayerController.playerPos.position.x);
```

Comment: And if Debug works fine then you need to check for your trigger.
Let me know if that helps

Comment: Okay, the Debug.Log worked fine, I just messed up with the name of the trigger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get an reference to the sphere. Then get it's Script you will get that position don't forget to use `Debug.Log();`. Let me know if it worked.